# Output from ruby command is not shown in STDOUT

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, terminal

I have the following script that outputs the name of a file that is being rendered as I make changes to another file:

```
jade --watch --pretty index.jade
```

Since I use this a lot in my project I decided to create a rake task that does this. But when I start the rake task the files get rendered but I no longer see the output.

I am aware that the output is somehow streamed to the STDOUT in this case which seems to behave differently than just executing say an `ls` command.

This is my Rakefile:

```
desc 'Watch .jade files'
task :watch do
  puts `jade --watch --pretty index.jade`
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're not seeing any output is that `jade` will block while it's running and only return when you kill it. If you were to kill it, you'd see the `puts` in effect.

What you want is to use `system`

```
system("jade --watch --pretty index.jade")
```

Which will use your process's STDOUT.

Comment: @besi That edit was absolutely not useful, or required. Please contribute real work instead of only working towards badges.